# Word macros disappear on transfer

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm using Word 2019 and have created macros I want to send to other organisations.

However, when I transfer the document (*.docm) or the template (*.dotm) the recipient doesn't get the macros (although everything else goes across).  On the Developer ribbon, there is no entry for the macro itself or the VBA code.

I know I can export the macro to a *.bas file which the recipient can then import but I'd like to do it directly.
There is no problem with transferring Excel macros but I can't get Word to work.
Can anybody help?

Comment: This is not a programming question, per se. Questions on general usage of Microsoft Word are off-topic for Stack Overflow and should be asked on an appropriate end-user forum. As for the problem itself, that is most likely related to either the recipients' macro-security settings or your the macro being in your installation's Normal template rather than the document or its template.

Comment: @macropod note that development/coding *related* questions can be [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) too even if there is no code involed directly. E.g. if it is related to *"software tools commonly used by programmers;"*. I don't think this is off-topic becaus it is clearly related to VBA development. The question is about VBA code/coding *in general* but not about Word in general.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely to have 2 possible reasons:

1. Did you really choose *"Word Macro-Enabled Document"* as file format? It could be that you saved a normal *"Word Document"* with the file extension `.docm`. Note that the file extension does **not** defined the file format.

   If this happend you have actually a Word document (without macros) but with the wrong file extension `.docm`. Make sure you choose the correct format not only the correct extension.

   You can easily test this:

   - Save your file as macro enabled file `docm`.
   - Close Word completely.
   - Re-Open your file. If the macro is still there your file format is correct.
2. If you send your file via email it can be that your recepient does not allow to recieve macro enabled files, and his email server is stripping off the macro from the Word file.

   If this is the case, then you cannot do much to prevent this. It is in the responsibility of the recepient. The only way to get through this kind of filter is to pack your file into a password protected zip archive so the email server cannot access the Word file. But not that doing so can violate the recepients policies. Also if the reciepient's company did it right they won't allow password protected zip archives via email because the could tunnel through their email filters.

   Best solution in this case it to provide the file via some cloud share (Google Drive, Dropbox, One Drive, what ever, …) and send the recipient a link only.

Comment: I've made some progress.  As an overview, I know it's not good practice to put everything in Normal.dotm so I have a named template.  When you display the Macro dialog here is a dropdown list for displaying/saving "Macros in:" 

I thought the option "All active templates and documents" would be OK, but in fact you have to use the named template.  I can now transfer the template and the macros arrive intact, but now I get a VBA error saying 'The macros in this project are disabled'.  I haven't been able to fix this through the Trust Center. Can anyone help me take the last step?

Answer (score 0):

That is because of your AV blocking macros to be saved in your PC. Macros have been used in the past by threat actors and Microsoft has applied a protection to them.

When you edit a document with macros, word creates a hidden file which is the macro you are running, now when you try to save that file, it gets caught by AV. Since AV thinks it is an evil activity. It gets saved on your system because your directory is now a [Trusted Location](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-7ee1cdc2-483e-4cbb-bcb3-4e7c67147fb4) and it is okay.

A workaround is to install Windows 7 with Microsoft Office 2007 to get what you want since Windows 7 has little to no security.

Thanks